# A loop to create a list

Tags: r

I would like to form a list thanks to a loop.

I have a list of variables called:

```
var1, var2, ... varN
```

And I would like to create easily a list of length named `listvar` with:

```
unlist(listvar[i])=vari   (with i in 1:N)
```

Is someone inspired ?

Answer (score 2):

The code makes me wonder why the variables `var1` … `varN` exist in the first place: they shouldn’t. Instead, generate the list directly.

That said, you can easily retrieve the value of a variable given by its name using `get`. This doesn’t even require a loop, you can use R’s vectorised operations.

```
varnames = paste0('var', 1 : N)
listvar = mget(varnames)
```

Comment: `mget(varnames)` may be a quicker way there.

Comment: @Pierre Yes of course! I always forget about `mget` …